# Find resulting column header value based off of row values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have a spreadsheet used for the tracking the demand of parts for a project.  What I need to be able to do is to input a part number, have a bit of code that finds the resulting row location, search to the right to find the first non-zero number, and then look up to find the value located in the first row.

Here is a pic of what I am trying to do.

[image]

Comment: We can help you achieve your goal but not write the whole thing for you. What do you have written so far?

Comment: @RoboNerd When do you want the code to run? automatic or manual? where do you want the result? did you try anything till now?

Comment: @Brian I got mad and scrapped everything I had because it just kept failing.  I was trying to use the index and match functions but as I said it just kept failing.  I'll try to recreate what I had and post it.

Comment: @aFast I would like to have the input linked to a cell on a different tab to where is can just have it run for every cell in a specific column so automatic.  The output will be placed next to the input cell on the aforementioned other tab.

Comment: So this is what I have so far.  The part that is non-existent is telling it to stop at the first non-zero item  It currently grabs the top most row value relative to the row location i.e. finds part 6 in second row then grabs the change in the second column. '=INDEX('Parts Required'!$E$1:$CG$1,MATCH(Sheet1!C15,'Parts Required'!$A:$A,0))'

Comment: so do you want "Change 7" or do you want "7" returned when the part number is 5?

Comment: @ForwardEd Change 7, so the exact string as entered.  It is safe to assume that everything in that row will be a text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX($E$1:$R$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($E$2:$R$3,MATCH($C$7,$A$2:$A$3,0),0)<>0,0))
```

where:

- $C$7 is the part number you are looking for.
- $A$2:$A$3 is your part number list.
- $E$2:$R$3 is your area below the change numbers.
- $E$1:$R$1 is your Change X header row.

It is a single cell ARRAY formula, so when you are editing the cell use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the formula, not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when you see { } around your formula in the formula bar.  Note the { } may not be entered manually.

PROOF OF CONCEPT

[image: proof of concept]

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me so much frustration :)